# how to utf-8 encode or typeface from assets using sax parse to set the list view android?

Tags: android, utf-8, saxparser

I want to need a font typeface from assets folder.so how to set font from assets in list view or sax parser set Unicode to work with all language

```
public class RssTabsActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rss_tabs);
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent artIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
        artIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://www.sandesh.com/cms/xml/National.xml");
                String artTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_art);
        TabSpec artTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(artTabName)
            .setIndicator(artTabName,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_art))
                                    .setContent(artIntent);
                                    tabHost.addTab(artTabSpec);
        Intent techIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
        techIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/technologyNews?format=xml");
        String techTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_tech);
        TabSpec techTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(techTabName)
                .setIndicator(techTabName,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_tech))
                                     .setContent(techIntent);
        tabHost.addTab(techTabSpec);
        Intent sportsIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, RssChannelActivity.class);
        sportsIntent.putExtra("rss-url", "http://www.globalgujaratnews.in/rss-gujarat-news/");
        String sportsTabName = getResources().getString(R.string.tab_sports);
        TabSpec sportsTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(sportsTabName)
                                       .setIndicator(sportsTabName, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rss_tab_sports))
                                       .setContent(sportsIntent);
        tabHost.addTab(sportsTabSpec);
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    }

public class RssReader {

        private String rssUrl;
        public RssReader(String rssUrl) {
                this.rssUrl = rssUrl;
         }
        public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
          SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
          SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
          RssParseHandler handler = new RssParseHandler();
          XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
          xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
          InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl);
          inputSource.setEncoding("UTF-8");
          saxParser.parse(inputSource, handler);
          return handler.getItems();        
       }
}

public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        private List<RssItem> rssItems;
        private RssItem currentItem;
        private boolean parsingTitle;
        private StringBuffer currentTitleSb;
        private boolean parsingLink;

        public RssParseHandler() {
            rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
        }

      public List<RssItem> getItems() {
            return rssItems;
       }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)                         throws SAXException {
        if ("item".equals(qName)) {
            currentItem = new RssItem();
            } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
                parsingTitle = true;
                currentTitleSb = new StringBuffer();
                } else if ("link".equals(qName)) 
            parsingLink = true;
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
           if ("item".equals(qName)) {
                rssItems.add(currentItem);
                currentItem = null;
           } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
              parsingTitle = false;
              if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setTitle(currentTitleSb.toString());
               }
          } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
              parsingLink = false;  }
       }

       @Override
       public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
          if (parsingTitle) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentTitleSb.append(new String(ch, start, length)); }
          } else if (parsingLink) {
            if (currentItem != null) {
                currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
                parsingLink = false; }  
         }
      }
}

public class RssItem {

        private String title;
        private String link;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

       public String getLink() {
          return link;
       }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
         return title;
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to set fonts in `ListView` of your application, Set font using this line of code, in `getView()` of your List adapter.
Show your `ListAdapter` code in case you can't figure it out.

`setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));`

Use below adapter like this -

```
SampleAdapter <RssItem> adapter = new SampleAdapter <RssItem>(local,R.layout.custom_row, result);
```

ArrayAdapter -

public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
RssItem data[] = null;

public SampleAdapter (Context context,int layoutResourceId, RssItem[] data) {
    super(context,layoutResourceId, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    RssItemHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RssItemHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(
                context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));
        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (RssItemHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    RssItem rssItem = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rssItem.title);

    return row;
}

static class RssItemHolder {

    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

custom_row.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:textSize="15px" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: thanks bro.. where I put this code so work      @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
             
            ListView Items = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssChannelListView);
                         
            ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
            Items.setAdapter(adapter);

             Items.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
        }

Comment: you willhave to make a custom adapter.http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92 , in that you will find a getview. There.

Comment: I try but didn't get a getview() method ? thanks advance

Comment: okay thank you so much So, can you show me with implemented setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.ttf"));  so I understand its work with listview not with textview

Comment: Changed my code. You will have to make an extra layout named `custom_row.xml`.and use this Adapter instead of your adapter.

Comment: Ohhh Thank you so much after All its work with textview than show in listview.. thanks bro

Comment: When any answer helps you out, and you find that considerable efforts have been put in it. you upvote/accept the answer. Welcome to StackOverFlow.